# WooCommerce Variations Attribute Label

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to modify a plugin (Eggplant Variations Add-to-Cart) with the desired result being that rather than the attribute slug being formatted and displayed, I want it to actually show the true value of the attribute.

For example, I have an attribute 'Option' with values 'Red & Green | Blue & Yellow'.  These are used for variations.  Currently this plugin will display 'Red Green' or 'Blue Yellow'.  This is due to this line:

```
printf( '<span class="attr attr-%s">%s</span>', $key, ucwords($val) );
```

All that is happening here is the slug is being converted so that the dashes and underscores are replaced with spaces and each word is capitalised first letter.

The variations and attributes are being retrieved via:

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
```

There is no reference point between these variables in order to retrieve the $attribute value using the $variations attribute slug.

How can I return the true attribute value (ie 'Red & Green', 'Blue & Yellow')?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
  $p=get_post_meta($product_id,'_product_attributes',true);

  $attr_value=$p['attribute_slug']['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Way past date, but this is your solution:

```
$taxonomy = str_replace( "attribute_",'', $key );
$meta = get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
$term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);

printf( '<span class="attr attr-%s">%s</span>', $key, $term->name );
```